Python App deployed in cPanel showing index of Page?
Index of/ Page Screenshot
When I set up a new scratch python project in the following manner:
Setup Python App -> New App -> (With SubDomain(something.yourdomain.com)) with Python 3 versions, after solving the previous problem stated here it's only showing the index of page.
What can really be the problem here?
I am truely clueless here, what to do? Should .htaccess file could be a reason or another reason?
If that's it what should be the structure of that respected file?
